# Optional Query Parameters in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Please help me in identifying the solution for the below problem.

I would like to get "Year" results from the Parameter, else all the results if the parameter is blank.

I have the date format(MMMM - YYYY) data in the Project_Start_Date field. Attached is the image for your reference.

Currently, I'm getting the results if the parameter is blank and if the parameter is entered with date, it is not working (not giving any results)

I tried the criteria - `Like IIf(IsNull([Date of the Year]),"*",Year([Date of the Year]))`

[image]

Comment: The format has no importance if `Project_Start_Date` is a _Date_ field. But is it a _text_ field?

Comment: No @Gustav, it's a Date/Time data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [Date of Year] DateTime;
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
    [Date of Year] Is Null Or 
    [Project_Start_Date] Between 
        DateSerial(Year(Nz([Date of Year],Date())),1,1) And 
        DateSerial(Year(Nz([Date of Year],Date())),12,31);
```

This will use an index on `[Project_Start_Date]` if present.

Comment: it is throwing an error while giving the parameter values. Error is "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated." I tried entering the date (01/01/2021) and also the year (2021) as a parameter. But it is throwing an error.

Comment: In the query, you may have to specify `[Date of Year]` as a _parameter_ of data type Integer.

Comment: I have added `[Date of Year]` as an Integer Data Type in Parameters, but it's throwing an error - "The value you entered isn't valid for this field"

Comment: Oh, right. See edited answer, please, with corrected info.

Comment: No @Gustav, I have tried the modified one, it is still throwing an error while the parameter value is empty. Error is "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated." And if the parameter value entered is Date, the results are empty.

Comment: It's `Year` that doesn't like a _Null_ value, so _Nz_ can be used to correct that. See adjusted answer, please.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gustav, it's working perfectly now.

And is it possible that we can give only the year in the parameter rather than the date?

Answer (score 0):

Make an expression with your WHERE statement field `Project_Start_date_Yr: Year([Project_Start_date])` and it should work.